# jqGrid what event gets triggered on search

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I want to be able to capture the words that people are searching on in the column search box for jqGrid. What event gets triggered when the column is searched? You can see a jqGrid example search here Searching > Toolbar with operations
http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: See this documentation page http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching

Answer (score 0):

```
    { name: "titleb", width: 347, sortable: false, editable: false, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn'], dataEvents: [{
    type: 'keypress', fn: function (event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        if($.trim($(this).val()))
        {
          RecordTitleSearchEvent('Product Searches', 'Title Search', 'Latest Releses PF Search', $.trim($(this).val()));
        }
       }
      }
    }]
} }
```

Above is what is in the grid. Below is what is in an external javascript file.

```
    function RecordTitleSearchEvent(category, action, label, searchedVal)
{
    if(!(typeof ga==='undefined') && ga)
    {
        searchedVal = searchedVal.replace(/'/g, "\&#39;");
        ga('set', 'dimension2', searchedVal);
        ga('send','event', category, action, label);
    } 
}
```